# php preg_replace two or more spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking to replace multiple instances of space characters.  My initial searches all seem to focus on using the `/s` but this includes newlines and other whitespace

I think this should be close?  replace two or more instances spaces `" "` with one space

```
preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: Looks fine as it is. What's the problem?

Comment: What is your question? The regex looks good!

Comment: really?  Must have been a good guess.  Been trying to find it for ages

Answer (score 4):

What about trying this :

```
preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want `\s`, because it does include not only spaces.

Comment: what does the `[]` brackets do. is it to help split up pattern so its easier to read?

Comment: @Robbo_UK Well, by using brackets, you search for ANY of the elements WITHIN the brackets... So, e.g. `[abc]` means "search for one of the three characters : a,b OR c. In your case, it includes just one character : space. So, basically to explain my regex, it reads : *"Search for one space. Then, search for AT LEAST one (more)space."* ==> In other words, for AT LEAST 2 spaces (one after the other)... :-)

Answer (score 2):

```php
$str = <<<EOT
word  word   123.

new line  word


new line  word
EOT;

$replaced = preg_replace('#\h{2,}#', ' ', $str);

var_dump($replaced);
```

output:

```text
word word 123.

new line word


new line word
```

`\h` matches any horizontal whitespace character (equivalent to `[[:blank:]]`)
`{2,}` matches the previous token between **2** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Credits: https://regex101.com/

Use `\v` for vertical whitespace, `\s` for any whitespace.

Comment: The `m` flag is useless for this pattern because the pattern contains no start or end anchors (`^` or `$`).  This answer is misleading researchers.